# Getting values from related entities cause error

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-2.3

I'm starting with `SonataAdminBundle` in my project but I'm having a issue getting related entities. I have this entity:

```
<?php

namespace PI\ProyectoBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="proyectos")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Proyectos {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=45, unique=true, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $nombre;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $estado;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=45, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $pais;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="PI\ClienteBundle\Entity\Clientes", cascade={"all"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="cliente", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $clientes;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="PI\CentroBundle\Entity\Centros", inversedBy="proyectos", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="proyectos_has_centros",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="proyectos_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
     *                   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="proyectos_cliente", referencedColumnName="cliente")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="centros_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     */
    protected $centros;

    /**
     * ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User", cascade={"persist"})
     * ORM\JoinTable(name="proyectos_has_system_user",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="proyectos_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
     *                   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="proyectos_cliente", referencedColumnName="cliente")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="system_user_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     */
    protected $ingenieros;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->centros = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->ingenieros = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setNombre($nombre) {
        $this->nombre = $nombre;
    }

    public function getNombre() {
        return $this->nombre;
    }

    public function setEstado($estado) {
        $this->estado = $estado;
    }

    public function getEstado() {
        return $this->estado;
    }

    public function setPais($pais) {
        $this->pais = $pais;
    }

    public function getPais() {
        return $this->pais;
    }

    public function setClientes(\PI\ClienteBundle\Entity\Clientes $clientes) {
        $this->clientes = $clientes;
    }

    public function getClientes() {
        return $this->clientes;
    }

    public function setCentros(\PI\CentroBundle\Entity\Centros $centros) {
        $this->centros[] = $centros;
    }

    public function getCentros() {
        return $this->centros;
    }

    public function setIngenieros(\BIT\UserBundle\Entity\User $ingenieros) {
        $this->ingenieros[] = $ingenieros;
    }

    public function getIngenieros() {
        return $this->ingenieros;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     */
    public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $eventArgs) {
        $em = $eventArgs->getEntityManager();
        $q = $em->createQuery('SELECT MAX(p.id) FROM PIProyectoBundle:Proyectos p');
        $id = $q->getSingleResult(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_SINGLE_SCALAR);
        $this->id = $id + 1;
    }

}
```

And  this is how I'm configuring the filter in **ProyectoAdmin.php** class:

```
protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $filter) {
    $filter
            ->add('nombre', null, array('label' => 'Nombre'))
            ->add('estado', null, array('label' => 'Estado'))
            ->add('pais', null, array('label' => 'País'))
            ->add('clientes', null, array('label' => 'Asignar Clientes'))
            ->add('ingenieros', null, array(), null, array('expanded' => true, 'multiple' => true))
            ->add('centros', null, array('label' => 'Asignar Centros'));
}
```

But I get this error:

> Notice: Undefined index: ingenieros in
>   /var/www/html/pingenieros/vendor/sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle/Sonata/DoctrineORMAdminBundle/Guesser/FilterTypeGuesser.php
>   line 64

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind was my bad, see this code:

```
/**
 * ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User", cascade={"persist"})
 * ORM\JoinTable(name="proyectos_has_system_user",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="proyectos_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
 *                   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="proyectos_cliente", referencedColumnName="cliente")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="system_user_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 */
protected $ingenieros;
```

Should be:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="proyectos_has_system_user",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="proyectos_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
 *                   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="proyectos_cliente", referencedColumnName="cliente")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="system_user_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 */
protected $ingenieros;
```

Notice the **@** before `ORM` definition, that was the problem anyway thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
->add('ingenieros', 'entity', array(
                  'class'    => 'AcmeMyBundle:Entity', //your ingenieros entity
                  'property' => 'name', // any class property
                  'multiple' => true,
                              'expanded' => true))
```